# Html.ActionLink is not working in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, foreach

I receive some data from another page. I try to loop through data and create a link. I get the data and put it in `@Html.ActionLink(GroupID, "GroupActivity", "Home")`. `GroupID` have value now.

But on screen it just shows the data but does not makes it a link.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Timetable", "Timetable", "Home")</li>
<li>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option selected>Select Group</option>
        @{ var GroupID = ""; }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option>
                @{ 
                    GroupID = item.GroupID.ToString();
                    ViewBag.SelectedGroup = GroupID;
                }
                @Html.ActionLink(GroupID, "GroupActivity", "Home") 
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</li>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euhQV.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to do here - having an `<a>` element in an `<option>` makes no sense - and its not valid (and why in the world are you doing `ViewBag.SelectedGroup = GroupID`?)

Comment: I have many groups in my list. Now I want to create links for every GroupID using @Html.ActionLink. But it does not make link in ActionLink

Comment: Did you not read my comment - An `<a>` tag is **not valid** in an `<option>` element (and why are you creating a `<select>` anyway - your code makes no sense)

Comment: <a> mean @ tag?

Comment: Than how can I generate DropDownList of multiple links dynamically.

Comment: You cant - its INVALID HTML! But why in the world do you want a `<select>` anyway - just use `@foreach (var item in Model) { @Html.ActionLink(GroupID, "GroupActivity", "Home", new { id = Model.GroupID }, null) }`

Comment: Thanks for help... It worked

Comment: Actually that was supposed to be `new { id = item.GroupID }` - but I assumed you worked that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write there something like this:

> Using Action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some text for link", "GroupActivity", "Home",new {GroupID=GroupID })
```

But in your case, this would not work because you are creating action link inside option which is invalid.

> Using client side event (onchange)

```
$(function(){
$("#YourDropDownID").change(function(){
     var selectedItem = $("#YourDropDownID option:selected").text();
     var redirectURL = '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")';
     window.location.href = redirectURL + "?item=" + selectedItem;
 }
}
```